# OrientDB Update Property via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientdb

Is there a way to update a property of a class via Javascript like:

```
results = mydb.command('sql',statement);
results[0].updateProperty("VariableToUpdate",variable);
mydb.commit();
```

At the moment I use a SQL command for the update and exute the command with js. But I think to update the property via a js-object is more clean and I didnt have to execute a 2nd SQL command for the update.

Btw can you recommend a docu, where I can find which functions are available for the js "results" object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
results[0].setProperty("VariableToUpdate",variable);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for fast response, that works. Can you recommend a docu, where I can find which functions are available for the js "results" object? Or where do you get your knowledge?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much documentation, information that I give you is from my personal experience

Comment: All info that you can get is only here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Javascript-Driver.html